# Using array to calculate percentage of number

Tags: c, arrays

So im trying to write a program that computes the percentage of one of the numbers in a group of numbers.İ can enter the numbers but the percentages are always 0 and i tried out the formula on paper and it works everytime sooo idk what seems to be the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x[10];
    int i,sum;
    float perc;
    sum=0;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        scanf("%d",&x[i]);
        sum=sum+x[i];
    }

    printf("n            percentage of total\n");

    for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        perc=(x[i]/sum)*100;
        printf("%d          %.2f\n",x[i],perc);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Just declare sum as float instead of integer.

Comment: Sorry, but this has been asked (and answered) a thousand times: Dividing two integers **truncates** the result to an integer.

Comment: If `sum` is defined as integer you should calculate `x[i] * 100 / sum`. The effect is, that if `x[i] * 100` is >= `sum` your result is > 0 too which is not the case otherwise. However decimal points are lost in this case.

Comment: Try casting both x[i] and sum to float before calculating, e.g., `((float) x[i]/(float) sum)*100`. Integer division never results a floating-point value.

Answer (score 5):

Change your declaration part as

```
   int i;
   float sum,perc;
   sum=0;
```

This is because of typecasting in c. 
The left side part in the figure showing what will the result if your result variable is integer and right side showing what will be the result if your result variable is float.

[image]

Comment: may i ask why you used float? The sum can be an integet too cant it

Comment: if you devide int with another int, the result will be int also.

Comment: because of Typecasting in c.For detail i will update my answer

Comment: @NezY Integers are floats, but floats aren't necessarily integers.

Comment: @speti43: Doesn't matter. If you FIRST multiply by 100, and THEN divide by another number, result will be correct.

Comment: @Thomas: Integers are NOT floats.

Comment: @SigTerm Jesus.. I was saying that integers can be assigned to floating-point variables, but the opposite is not true. I was replying to OP's first comment. Calm down, will you?

Comment: @Thomas: "A can be assigned to B" != "A is B". It means "A can be converted to B". Oh, and if you assign big 64bit integer (2^63-1, for example) to single-precision float, there will be data loss.

Comment: @SigTerm I *know* that. I was dumbing it down for Nez Y to avoid millions of follow-up questions eventually leading to detailing the entire IEEE spec along with every page of the C standard which ever discussed floating-point types.

Comment: @Thomas: IMO, if "dumbing down" means giving completely incorrect information, you shouldn't do it. And if you don't want to explain the whole thing yourself, give him a [link to existing material](http://floating-point-gui.de/). The dude will have to figure out floating points and type conversion at some point anyway.

Comment: @NezY: The sum can be an integer, you are correct. If you declare `sum` as `int`, then typecast either `sum` or `x[i]` to `float` at the division.

Answer (score 2):

This expression

> perc=(x[i]/sum)*100;

performs integer division. Integer division returns no fractional part.

If `(x[i] >= 0)` and  `(x[i] < sum)`, then `(x[i]/sum)` is zero. (100 * 0) is also zero.

Either FIRST multiply by 100 and THEN divide (you won't get fractional part of percentage this way, though):

```
perc=(x[i]*100/sum);
```

Or convert arguments to floats:

```
perc=((float)x[i]*100.0/(float)sum);
```

or

```
perc = x[i] * 100.0f / sum;
```

Comment: I like the explicit conversions, but worth to write is the version with implicit conversions: `perc = x[i] * 100.0f / sum;` keeping the variable declarations as they are. Question of taste.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting result zero because dividing an `int` will always result in an `int`. If denominator becomes greater than numerator then it will give `0`.
Take advantage of `typecasting`, change

```
perc=(x[i]/sum)*100;
```

to

```
perc= ((float)x[i]/sum)*100; //Typecasting
```

You can also do this by changing `100` to `100.0` as

```
perc= (x[i]*100.0/sum);
```